# Angular method not returning value

Tags: angular, methods, self-executing-function

I have a API call which fetches me a Random Image. I am trying to call following method and trying to use the variable returned, but it's only givig me empty results.

```
  fetchRandomArt():RawImportData<Artdata>{

    var tempRand:RawImportData<Artdata> = new  RawImportData<Artdata>();
    this.dataService.getRandomArt<RawImportData<Artdata>>().subscribe(
      (res: RawImportData<Artdata>) => {
        if(res){
          tempRand = res;
          this.isLoading=false;
        }
      },
      err => {throw("Can't connect to Server.")}
    );
    console.log("tempRand");
    console.log(tempRand);
    return tempRand;

  }
```

However i tested that API is indeed giving me result (inside `if(res)` diplays data), but i am not able to use that data outside the function.

Also, Is it possible to self execute this fuction after every 5 seconds?

**EDIT:**

I just noticed, the inner function is executing later,

```
out tempRand
RawImportData {}
in tempRand
{records: Array(1), pagination: {…}}
```

I know i can solve this by calling and subscribing n times, but i want to use values returned by this function only as i want it to self call.

**UPDATE**

Just want to update that the links tagged to this question do not answer this question, however following method does,

```
  public async fetchRandomArt():Promise<RawImportData<Artdata>>{
    const data = await this.dataService.getRandomArt<RawImportData<Artdata>>().toPromise();
    this.isLoading=false;
    console.log(data); 
    return data;
  }
```

Comment: As for your update, the accepted answer in duplicate here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6294072 presents the `async await` option :)

Comment: But i am not able to use the results in my HTML! It's saying, `<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->`

Comment: This is how i'm using, `*ngFor="let art of fetchRandomArt().records | async"`

Comment: I don't know what you have changed currently, but as is it sits `fetchRandomArt()` returns nothing, as this is asynchronous. Also `async` pipe expects an Observable.

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation to understand this, this will answer your questions: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#asyncpipe

Comment: Its a `Promise`?

Comment: no it's not, it's now a an object (assumingly). Store it then in a variable named as you wish, for example `randomArt` and iterate `*ngFor="let art of randomArt.records"`. Thoiugh, I prefer embracing observables instead of the `async await` approach. Observables are so versatile and have amazing operators, so I suggest you dig into those at some time and then you can see the benefits :)

Comment: Thanks man, you've been of great help for last 2 days! (edit) I just wanted myself a sweet slideshow by calling this async function evey 5 second, looks like i have to go back to using multiple fixed observables.

Comment: You are welcome for the help. Hard to help further on your slideshow-thing when not seeing code. There would probably be a nice observable solution with rxjs operators for that (is just a guess!), but cannot give any tips without seeing code. You can consider asking a new question if there is some specific issue that you need solved.

Comment: @AJT82 Sorry for being totally out of context, but I really want you to see I made the slideshow :) mgoart.web.app (scroll down the home page)

Comment: Great! One does always feel like a champion when accomplishing something that been struggling with! :) :)